# How to use append in for loop for multiple value list when only a single value is returning?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that when passed a list of names of any length, will return a list of only those names that are exactly four characters in length. I want the output list to be comma delimited.

I have attached code of what I have tried. I tried to get the function to iterate through the list parameter passed to the function `'x'` and then if the length of that list value is four characters long, add it to the output list.

I expected the output list to be `['Ryan','Mary']` but it's just `['Ryan']` as is.

I'm new to all this and don't understand why what I've done isn't working.

```
output = []
def friend(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if len(x[i]) == 4:
            return output.append(x[i])

list = ["Ryan","Kieran","Jason","Mary"]
friend(list)
print(output)
```

Comment: as you have seen, return ends the function and returns the value. So, you need to collect the values, and only return after youve finished collecting all the values. (hint: after/outside the loop)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to return so early.  you are not giving your function enough passes through your list to get more than 1 element with 4 letters.  You want to take time to build your list before returning it.  I would build up the output list then, once we are done looping entirely, return it:

````
def friend(x):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if len(x[i]) == 4:
            output.append(x[i])
    return output

list = ["Ryan","Kieran","Jason","Mary"]
myOutput = friend(list)
print(myOutput)```
````

Comment: OP, another thing to note is that you can iterate the elements directly, you don't need `range`, you can just use `for i in x`, then `if len(i) == 4`

Answer (score 2):

There are actually numerous ways to tackle this issue

One way is list comprehension:

```
list = ["Ryan","Kieran","Jason","Mary"]

print([name for name in list if len(name) == 4]) # iterate list using variable name, check if len(name) == 4, and add it to the list if it's true
```

Another way is making use of yield:

```
def friend(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if len(x[i]) == 4:
            yield x[i] # note that this returns a generator, not a list. Basically, you can only iterate once
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using list comprehension, you can shorten your function like :

```
def friend(x):
    return [k for k in x if len(k)==4]
list_ = ["Ryan","Kieran","Jason","Mary"]
print(friend(list_))
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['Ryan', 'Mary']
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I want to add that you should not use `list` (and other types names) as variable name. Also alternatively to list comprehension you might use `filter` function, example usage:

```
lst = ["Ryan","Kieran","Jason","Mary"]
output = list(filter(lambda x:len(x)==4,lst))
print(output) #['Ryan', 'Mary']
```

Note that `filter` requires function which takes element of `lst` as argument and `return`s `False` (jettison) or `True` (retain). I want to note that personally I find list comprehension more readable in this case and I just wanted to show function `filter` which could be encountered in situation requiring choice of certain elements from `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension

```
    output = [name for name in list_of_names if len(name)==4]
    print(output)
```